# What is the solution of greatest possible dimension for this decoupled linear subspace problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $\left\{A_i\right\}$ be a $k$-element set of $n\times n$ Hermitian matrices, and let $P$ be an $n\times n$ rank-$m$ orthogonal projection matrix. We consider the projection of any matrix $A$ onto $P$ to be $PAP$.

Let $P_s$ be a rank $s < m$ orthogonal sub-projection of $P$ such that $P_s\mathcal{H}_{n} P_s \subset P\mathcal{H}_{n} P$, with $\mathcal{H}_n$ the set of all $n\times n$ Hermitian matrices, and let $\mathcal{S}$ be the set of all such sub-projections.

Finally, let $P_s^{\perp} = \mathbf{1} - P_s$ be the complementary projection of $P_s$.

Consider a decoupling problem of the form (1):

$$P_s\left( \sum _i u_i A_i\right) P_s^\perp = 0$$

with $u_1,\ldots ,u_k \in \mathbb{R}$.

I wish to find the linear constraints on $u_i$ such that (1) holds.

For any one $P_s$, this is a simple exercise since we have

$$u_1\left( P_s A_1 P_s^\perp\right) + u_2\left( P_s A_2 P_s^\perp\right) + \cdots + u_k\left( P_s A_k P_s^\perp\right) = 0$$ and hence we find $\vec{u}$ to be any vector in $\ker B$ where $B$ is the column-concatenated matrix $$\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {\operatorname{vec} {P_s}{A_1}P_s^ \bot }&{\operatorname{vec} {P_s}{A_2}P_s^ \bot }& \cdots &{\operatorname{vec} {P_s}{A_k}P_s^ \bot } 
\end{array}} \right)$$

If $P_s$ is unknown, the problem is trickier.

**My question is as follows:** Is there a way to determine whether there exists a $P_s \in \mathcal{S}$ such that the solution for $\vec{u}$ in (1) is nontrivial, and if so, what is that $P_s$?

In particular I'm looking for the projection $P_s$ such that the vector space of solutions for $\vec{u}$ has the greatest possible dimension.

Any help would be much appreciated.